# Can I direct base to BaseController in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code :

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOrderedProductService _orderedProductService;

    public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IOrderedProductService orderedProductService)
            : base(dbContext)
    {
        _orderedProductService = orderedProductService;
    }
}
```

In an ASP.NET MVC project, where `base(dbContect)` is meant to be `BaseController.BaseController(ApplicationDbContext dbContect)`, but it has become `Controller.Controller()` instead.

How do I fix it?

Comment: `ProductController : Controller` might be a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `ProductController` inherits from `Controller` - its base is `Controller`.

The reference of `base(dbContect)` correctly points to `Controller.Controller()`.

In order for the `base(dbContect)` to call in to `BaseController.BaseController(ApplicationDbContext dbContect)` you will need to alter your class definition to be:

```
public class ProductController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IOrderedProductService _orderedProductService;

    public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IOrderedProductService orderedProductService)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
        _orderedProductService = orderedProductService;
    }
}
```

This will change the base class of `ProductController` to be `BaseController` and the call to the base contructor will be as you desire.

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty big explaination for just a `BaseController` `!=` `Controller` :P

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new class name BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
  private readonly DbContext dbContext;
  public BaseController(DbContext dbContext) {
     this.dbContext = dbContext;
  }
}
```

then you should inherit your ProductController like:

```
public class ProductController : BaseController {
   public ProductController(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext){
   } 
}
```